# Stirling Numbers of the First Kind Proof

Tags: combinatorics, induction

Prove the following:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{r}|s(n,k)| = n! - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} - |s(n,k+r+1)|$$

Workings:

Proof:

Base case: $n = 0, r = 0$

$s(0,0) = 1$

$0! - s(0,0+0+1) = 1 - 0 = 1$

Base case holds

Induction hypothesis:

Suppose $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{r} |s(n,k)| = n! - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} - |s(n,k+r+1)|$ holds for some $n$.

Then for $n+1$:

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{r} |s(n+1,k)| = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{r} |s(n,k-1)| + n|s(n,k)|$

I don't know what to do next and I believe what I did so far is incorrect.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you didn't mean the double negative on the RHS:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{r}|s(n,k)| +  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}|s(n,k+r+1)|$$

$$= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{r}|s(n,k)| +  \sum\limits_{k={r+1}}^{n+r+1}|s(n,k)|$$

$$= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{r}|s(n,k)| +  \sum\limits_{k={r+1}}^{n}|s(n,k)|$$

$$ \text{ (since } s(n,k) = 0 \text{ for }k > n)$$

$$= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}|s(n,k)| $$

$$= n!$$

Comment: Yes I didn't mean the double negative.